# Run startup commands in spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The `-i` option for `scala` repl does not work with `spark-shell` : it silently ignores the option. Specifically:

```
spark-shell -i ~/.scalarc
```

does not load the `~/.scalarc` file

Is there another means to load startup (scala) commands into the spark-repl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be a later development, but I just tried spark-shell -i init.scala and it ran my init.scala script after it finished starting up.

Comment: oh nice! checking it out now - if it works i'll award your answer

Comment: it *does* work now - they apparently did fix that oversight.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to use :load

```
:load /Users/steve/.scalarc
```

spark-shell does not support some command line parameters nor does it support `:power` mode .

**Update** as of Spark 2.0 the `spark-shell -i <initfilepath>` is now supported. See the accepted answer by Vijay.